# Ничком и навзничь

Tags: этимология

Упасть ничком — значит "лицом вниз", а навзничь — "на спину". А почему так говорят?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

НИЧКОМ.
  В основе лежит "ник" - древнерусское сущ. со значением "низ", "обратная сторона". Из него образовано "ником" - "спиной кверху, лицом
 вниз", (ср. "приникнуть", "поникнуть" и т. п.),а затем и "ничком"

НАВЗНИЧЬ.
  Было древнее наречие "навзнак" - лицом вверх.  Затем наречие это изменилось под влиянием "ничком" - лицом к земле .В результате оба наречия стали походить друг на друга, а по смыслу стали антонимами(лицом вниз-лицом вверх)